# Difference between auto and auto* when storing a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Is there a functional difference between the following? Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

```
auto p = new C();
```

and

```
auto* p = new C();
```

Comment: No differences whatsoever, use whichever you prefer. However, if the expression being deduced is not of pointer type when `auto*` is used, then you'll get a compiler error while in the former case you won't.

Comment: `auto` will add the pointer for you. It's the same

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the snippet you have given there is no difference.    The compiler will deduce that `p` will be a pointer to `C`, either way.

In a more general case, there is a difference. For example;

```
auto *p = func();

auto p = func();
```

The first form will cause an error message if `func()` returns something that is not a pointer, but the second will not.    This is sometimes useful (e.g. in templated code) where there is a need to enforce a requirement that `func()` return a pointer rather than (say) an `int`. [Although, admittedly, there are more clear and powerful ways to enforce such a requirement, such as traits].

As noted by John Ilacqua in comments, there are further benefits of using `auto *`, including `const` qualification of the pointer.  For example, `const auto * p = func()` specifies that `p` points at something that is `const` or `const auto * const p = func()` specifies that `p` points at something that is `const` AND `p` cannot be reassigned.    Such qualification will also result in diagnostics if `const` qualifiers on the return type of `func()` are incompatible.

Comment: I would suggest that there is an additional benefit to using `auto*` - it allows you to declare that the pointer is `const` if you so desire:

`const auto* const p = func();`